# Conditional compilation based on string passed in macro

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a macro of the form:

```
#define SAMPLE_MACRO(x) somefunction(x)
```

I invoke the macro with strings as parameter:

```
SAMPLE_MACRO("abc");
SAMPLE_MACRO("bbe");
SAMPLE_MACRO("ccb");
SAMPLE_MACRO("axx");
```

Is it possible to make the preprocessor parse the string so that if lets say it starts with an "a" (so strings "abc" and "axx" in the above example) the macro will call some other function and not somefunction()? In other words I do not want to add an "if" statement inside the macro that is executed at runtime and compares the string, but I want to have the macro have different behavior depending on the string parameter specified at compilation. I presume this may involve adding some #ifdef inside the macro. Is this possible in C++11?

Comment: No it is not possible.    You're asking for the preprocessor - which modifies source code before it is compiled - to do runtime checks.   Use of `#ifdef` within a macro is not possible.      Even if you weren't asking the near-impossible, using preprocessor macros with arguments considered BAD PRACTICE in C++ for several reasons.   Write some other function that checks its arguments, and calls other the functions.   And eliminate the macro.entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. You can create a string from a parameter name, but can't parse the contents of a parameter.

Sounds like you would essentially be creating a different macro for each string condition anyway, so simplest is to just use a different name for each condition, as in:

```
#define SAMPLE_MACRO(x) somefunction(x)
#define SAMPLE_MACRO_A(x) otherfunction(x)
```

If the macro is multiple lines, and you only want a single line to be different, one way is to pass the function name as a macro parameter:

```
#define SAMPLE_MACRO(f, x) { \
    ...
    f(x);
    ...
}
```

Call it somewhere:

```
SAMPLE_MACRO(otherfunction, "abc");
SAMPLE_MACRO(somefunction, "bbe");
```

Another alternative is to make macros for the other lines, and use those in the specific macros:

```
#define SAMPLE_MACRO_PRE(x) ...
#define SAMPLE_MACRO_POST(x) ...

#define SAMPEL_MACRO(x) { \
    SAMPLE_MACRO_PRE(X); \
    somefunction(x); \
    SAMPLE_MACRO_POST(x); \
}
#define SAMPEL_MACRO_A(x) { \
    SAMPLE_MACRO_PRE(X); \
    otherfunction(x); \
    SAMPLE_MACRO_POST(x); \
}
```

This is all stuff that applies to C as well. If you want to be object oriented, consider making classes to handle the differences in the strings, rather than macros. Inherit from a base type, and have different implementations of the .somefunction() member function. Proper object orientation can eliminate a lot of switch() or cascading if() statements.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to prematurely optimise something. If this is the case then it should be noted that you don't actually need to. The compiler should trivially optimise out the conditional statement due to the fact that the data is constant.

The following compiles without any conditional branching,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define SAMPLE_MACRO(x) (x[0] == 'a' ? somefunction1(x) : somefunction2(x))

void somefunction1(const char* arg){
    std::cout << "fn1 " << arg << std::endl;
}
void somefunction2(const char* arg){
    std::cout << "fn2 " <<  arg << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    SAMPLE_MACRO("abc");
    SAMPLE_MACRO("def");
    return 0;
}
```

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        call    somefunction1(char const*)
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC3
        call    somefunction2(char const*)
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

[Godbolt Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/NFJDR3)